# SQL Server - can I load MDF without LDF file without losing data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a backup database file (i.e. test.mdf), however, I don't have the LDF file. I was told that SQL Server 2008 R2 can load MDF without LDF.

Is that true?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the database was detached cleanly, you should be able to use [sp_attach_single_file_db](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174385.aspx) or the newer [CREATE DATABASE...FOR ATTACH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) syntax.

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db 
    @dbname = 'YourDB', 
    @physname = N'C:\YourFile.mdf';
```

OR

```
CREATE DATABASE YourDB
      ON (FILENAME = 'c:\YourFile.mdf') 
      FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

Comment: I assure that the DB was detached cleanly. So you mean I will not lose any data? thank you

Comment: No, you may lose data depending on what was in the LDF - the transaction log.

Comment: @q0987: To guarantee no data loss, the SQL Server service would have to have been stopped.

Comment: Hello all, The target database has no transaction data and only contain static data

Comment: @q0987: In that case, you *should* be OK.

Comment: Quite interesting, if I directly attach the MDF file and igore LDF in my sql 2005 or 2008, I can load the db without problems. I don't know why people here uses a little complicated way. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another option to `sp_attach_single_file_db` is the [CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) command with the FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG option.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me. I used EMERGENCY mode to see database:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1903548.aspx

> You have two options:
>
> 1. You can create an empty database with the same name and physical file layout, shut down the server, swap in the files you want to
>      attach in place of the empty DB files, and start the server.  The
>      database should come up in suspect mode.  You can then ALTER DATABASE
>       SET EMERGENCY to put it in emergency mode, and then run DBCC
>      CHECKDB REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS.  This will pull as much data as
>      possible out of the log to make the database consistent, but may have
>      to delete some data in order to make the database consistent.  This is
>      the option which is most likely to get the maximum data back.
> 2. You can attempt to use the CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG to see if that will bring it back.  If the database was cleanly shut
>      down, you MIGHT be able to succeed.  There is also the chance that the
>      database will be inconsistent or corrupt if there are transactions
>      which could not be rolled back.  You should in any event run DBCC
>      CHECKDB REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS to make your database consistent.  In
>      this event, SQL Server will make no attempt to mine information from
>      the log.  It will ignore the contents of the log.  If there were
>      transactions in process no rollback will be possible, so the
>      ALLOW_DATA_LOSS will be required.
>
> For more please try to refer to:
>
> http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/21/sql-server-fix-error-9004-an-error-occurred-while-processing-the-log-for-database-if-possible-restore-from-backup-if-a-backup-is-not-available-it-might-be-necessary-to-rebuild-the-log/